# Why can't I get ddrescue to clone a drive with an extended partition?

Tags: partitioning, ddrescue

I'm trying to clone a drive with a number of partitions (using an old live DVD); however, the result ends up with the extended partition being empty.  This is the command and the result:

```
mint@mint ~ $ sudo ddrescue -fnv /dev/sda /dev/sdb /home/mint/resc.log
GNU ddrescue 1.19
About to copy 320072 MBytes from /dev/sda to /dev/sdb.
    Starting positions: infile = 0 B,  outfile = 0 B
    Copy block size: 128 sectors       Initial skip size: 128 sectors
Sector size: 512 Bytes

Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
rescued:   320072 MB,  errsize:       0 B,  current rate:   13918 kB/s
   ipos:   320072 MB,   errors:       0,    average rate:   18668 kB/s
   opos:   320072 MB, run time:    4.76 h,  successful read:       0 s ago
Finished
```

- 

```
Disk /dev/sda: 298.1 GiB, 320072933376 bytes, 625142448 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xefa8efa8

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1            2048  24578047  24576000  11.7G 27 Hidden NTFS WinRE
/dev/sda2  *     24578048  24782847    204800   100M  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3        24782848 137422847 112640000  53.7G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda4       137422848 625141759 487718912 232.6G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       137424896 149712895  12288000   5.9G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda6       149714944 625141759 475426816 226.7G 83 Linux


Disk /dev/sdb: 465.8 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xefa8efa8

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1            2048  24578047  24576000  11.7G 27 Hidden NTFS WinRE
/dev/sdb2  *     24578048  24782847    204800   100M  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdb3        24782848 137422847 112640000  53.7G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdb4       137422848 625141759 487718912 232.6G  5 Extended
```

Or in gparted:

https://funkyimg.com/i/36ns9.jpg
https://funkyimg.com/i/36ns7.jpg

The logfile shows nothing of note:

```
# Rescue Logfile. Created by GNU ddrescue version 1.19
# Command line: ddrescue -fnv /dev/sda /dev/sdb /home/mint/resc.log
# Start time:   2020-07-19 03:11:04
# Current time: 2020-07-19 07:56:48
# Finished
# current_pos  current_status
0x4A85D50000     +
#      pos        size  status
0x00000000  0x4A85D56000  +
```

I can't find any mention of special handling for extended partitions.  Is there something I'm missing or a better way to do this?

Comment: Were `fdisk` and `gparted` run after or before `ddrescue` finished?

Comment: These specific captures were after the last attempt.  The only difference is that the destination disk initially started out empty.

Comment: same issue here